Alternative approach to solve problem via composition of velocities
The problem consists of two trains with proper length $L_0$ going at the same velocity and in the opposite direction. In the perspective of an observer inside either of the trains, it measures a time $\Delta T$ between its train's front meeting the other's reer and the other's front meeting its reer. The problem asks what's the speed that an IRF would have to travel at to see both events happen simultaneously.
The solution provided by our professor was using a diagram and it can also be done through a Lorentz transformation between the observer's frame and the IRF's they ask about.
Make sure to point out if the following diagram contains any mistakes:

From this figure you can infere that both events, $(0,L_0)$ and $(c\Delta T,0)$, should lie on the $x''$ axis (or at least a line parallel to it) of the IRF in order for them to occur simultaneously. Since the spatial axis $x''$ is described by $\Delta x^{0}=\beta''\Delta x$, then, with $\Delta x^{0}=c\Delta T$ and $\Delta x=-L_0$ we find
$$\beta''=\frac{\Delta x^{0}}{\Delta x}=\frac{c\Delta T}{-L_0}\iff \boxed{v''=-\frac{c^2\Delta T}{L_0}}$$
Either way, with the Lorentz transform $\Lambda_{v''}:S\to S''$ and imposing $\Delta x^{0''}=0$ we end up with the same result:
$$\Delta x^{0''}=0=\gamma_{v''}(\Delta x^0-\beta''\Delta x)\iff \boxed{v''=-\frac{c^2\Delta T}{L_0}}$$

This post's purpose was to ask for a way to obtain the same result employing velocity composition since a colleague told the professor in class he did it via two velocity additions and the professor confirmed it is also correct. The thing is I couldn't derive it myself so I asked here...
